# How can I assign a Keyboard Shortcut to "Run SQL" in RAD7 / Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, rad

When developing in Rational Application Developer 7 I regularly run SQL queries to confirm DB state and get info for test data. I have a .SQL file with various SQL snippets in it which I use and can highlight the relevant lines I want to run. However I then have to right click with the mouse and select "Run SQL" from the menu.

There is no keyboard shortcut assigned to this command and my attempts to set one up via

```
Window > Preferences > General > Keys
```

have been unsuccessful. "Run SQL" appears under "uncategorized" rather than "Run" but attempts to assign a keyboard shortcut to it have been unsuccessful.

Has anyone else come across this issue? I can't believe I'm the only one who finds this annoying when there are so many other shortcuts set up to speed things up...

Answer (score 1):

From the [bug 238890](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=238890) (2008), this feature has never been intended to become a full run configuration.

> The user should use 'Execute Selected' context menu. The 'Run' is designed for
>   running stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks @VonC but it looks like the 'Execute Selected' didn't make it into RAD 7, Run SQL appears to be the only option...